# Jquery is it possible set alias for div with ID?

Tags: jquery, svg, alias, identifier, svg-edit

I try to implement my own button into SVG Editor. Svg editor has many buttons with ID's and funcionality. Now I would like to implement more buttons on one page with different IDs but with the same funcionality as original button. Because of tons of code in svg editor is hard to find and implement all events of other buttons on right places. Exist any way to implement something like "ID alias" ? So that i create button with new ID and it will have same function as button with original ID ?

Comment: actually what you are looking for is class. Add the same class to all the buttons (original and added ones) and edit the code once to refer to the class instead of id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lelio suggested you should set a class on all the buttons you want to share functionality.

```
<button class="classname">Press me</button>
```

You can then access them easily using jquery;

```
$(".classname")
```

You prepend the name with a . to match on the class, or a # to match on the ID field.

Comment: Yes it is sollution. But only problem is I must change original code of events in original files and not sure if I can change and find all included files to work it correctly.  Does exist any  other sollution it refers class to div (something like alias) ? So that I need not change original files with declared events ? Or the class is one and only sollution ?

Comment: You can put a class on a <div> and then if that <div> contains all the buttons you have then you could do: $(".divclass :button").each(){} which would run a function for each button in that div. This would cut down the amount of work you would need to do refactoring the classes into your existing code.